# infinite loop after the user input

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes, infinite-loop

our professor asked as to used linked list and pointers to perform the ADT list operations.
There's no error when compiling it. but every function ends up in an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
char choice;

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *link;
};

typedef struct node *list;
list *head;

void print(list *head)
{
    list ptr=NULL;
    if (*head!=NULL)
    {
        for (ptr=*head; ptr->link!=NULL; ptr=ptr->link)
            cout<< ptr->value <<" ";
        cout<<ptr->value;
    } //if
    else
        cout<<"NOTHING TO PRINT!";
 } //print

void add(list *head)
{
     int num;
     list ptr;
     cout<<"What do you want to add: ";
     cin>>num;
     cout<<"Options: "<<endl<<"A. Addtail"<<endl<<"B. Addhead"<<endl
                 <<"Choice : ";
     cin>>choice;

     switch(choice)
     {
         case 'a':
         case 'A':
         {
             list newnode,ptr;
             ptr=*head;
             newnode=(list)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             while(ptr->link!=NULL)
                ptr=ptr->link;
             ptr->link=newnode;
             newnode->value=num;
             newnode->link=NULL;
             break;
         } // case a
         case 'b':
         case 'B': 
         {
             list newnode;
             newnode = (list)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
             newnode->value=num;
             newnode->link=*head;
             *head=newnode;
             break;
         } // case b
     } // switch

     print(head);
 } // add

void deleted(list *head)
{
     list ptr;
     cout<<"Options: "<<endl<<"A. Deletetail"<<endl<<"B. Deletehead"<<endl
                 <<"Choice : ";
     cin>>choice;

     switch(choice)
     {
     case 'a':
     case 'A':
          {
              list ptr,ptr2;

              ptr=*head;
              if(*head!=NULL)
              {
                 while(ptr->link!=NULL)
                 {
                     ptr2=ptr;
                     ptr=ptr->link;
                 } //while
                 free(ptr);
                 ptr2->link=NULL;
              }//if
              else
                 cout<<"Nothing to delete!";
          }//case a
     case 'b':
     case 'B':
          {
              list ptr;
              if(*head!=NULL)
              {
                  ptr=*head;
                  *head=ptr->link;
                  free(ptr);
              }
              else
                  cout<<"Nothing to delete!";
          }//case b
     }//switch

     print(head);
 }//delete


 void empty(list *head)
 {
      if (*head !=NULL)
          cout<<"The list is not Empty"<<endl<<endl;
      else
          cout<<"The List is Empty"<<endl<<endl;
  }//empty

  void makenull(list *head)
  {
       *head = NULL;
       print(head);
  }//makenull



main ()
{
     int dota=0;
     while(dota<10)
     {
         cout<<"ADT List Operations:"<<endl<<"A. Add"<<endl<<"B. Delete"<<endl<<
                "C. Empty"<<endl<<"D. Make Null"<<endl<<"E. Print"<<endl<<"F. Exit"<<endl
                <<"Choice: ";
         cin>>choice;
         switch(choice)
         {
             case 'a':
             case 'A': {add(head);break;}
             case 'b':
             case 'B': {deleted(head);break;}
             case 'c':
             case 'C': {empty(head);break;}
             case 'd':
             case 'D': {makenull(head);break;}
             case 'e':
             case 'E': {print(head);break;}
             case 'f':
             case 'F': {dota=100;break;}
         }//switch
     }//while

     cout<<"Do you want to try again?"<<endl<<"Choice : ";
     cin>>choice;
     if(choice =='Y' || choice =='y')
           {makenull(head); main();}

     system("pause");
 }//main
```

im a newbie sorry. what seems to be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'a':
     case 'A':
     {
         list newnode,ptr;
         ptr=*head;
         newnode=(list)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
         while(ptr->link!=NULL)
            ptr=ptr->link;
         ptr->link=newnode;
         newnode->value=num;
         newnode->link=NULL;
         break;
     } // case a
```

When you come into the program you have to makenull first so that head is NULL.  But see the add code.  If head is NULL you never actually set the head pointer to a valid node...  that is why you are crashing on add to tail.  I am assuming the other paths also have similar issues.  The memory was never initialized properly.

Comment: i ran the program and after the 
     cout<<"Options: "<<endl<<"A. Addtail"<<endl<<"B. Addhead"<<endl
                 <<"Choice : ";
     cin>>choice;
it crashes. 
yeah i know. thanks for the tip about the head im a newbie in those kind of stuff.

Comment: Well, okay thats a lot different than an infinite loop.  In a new program do this:  while(true) {} and see what happens... thats an infinite loop.  So you crash on cin >> choice; I remember something funny with cin and chars let me do some research

Comment: it still crashes after the user inputs. even in other functions. it still crashes. dont know whats the problem.

Comment: even the third option?  Problem is that you cannot cin >>  to a char.  You can cin to a char * or a string... if you input a number it may work for the char...  best to just switch to numbers anyway, its cleaner unless its a req to use char.

Comment: yeah. the cin in the main function works well but after the user inputs whether its addtail or addhead it crashes. i thinks its in the loop or its a bad pointer but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: ok.  so if the input is not crashing it, then that means one of the things you are doing is crashing it.  Two ways to debug this.  One you could run it in GDB and see what line it crashes on and that will give you a big clue.  Or Two: You could put some logging into the function you are running to get an idea of why its crashing.  I think you are at that point and it will also let you know if the cin is crashing and if you are getting into the code

Comment: oh!  Dude! When did you alloc the head?  So in your add function, you dereference link on an unset pointer.  You have to in your main set *head to null, and in your add and delete functions take into account the fact that they may be adding or deleting the head

Answer (score 0):

Nice code, try this instead

In void makenull(list *head) function you have an infinite loop because that you haven't 
free the link of the head. so it obviously an infinite loop.
so try this...

```
   void makenull(list *head)
   {

   (*head)->value = NULL;//make data empty

   (*head)->link = NULL;//make link empty

    print(head);

  }//makenull
```

Hope this works.

Comment: He never malloced the head node and he never handles the head node in the other functions.